# Expresso Store - PHP Error - store/mcp.store.php

Tags: expresso-store

I just moved a site to a new server and everything is working beautifully except for Store. In CP, I see this PHP errors.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant STORE_CP already defined
Filename: store/mcp.store.php
Line Number: 9
```

The front-end has this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Store_cart::count_contents()
in /public_html/manager/expressionengine/third_party/store/mod.store.php 
on line 55
```

Store 1.6.3, EE 2.5.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the PHP error, it sounds like the files weren't uploaded correctly. I would delete the entire `third_party/store` folder from your server and try uploading it again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a permissions issue. If you make sure the `store` directory in the `third_party` folder has correct permissions (maybe 755) then that may fix it...?